# Can I use the margin attribute to center the body?

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to have the body centered by adding margins on each side. Unfortunately nothing happens to the body tag when I attribute margins to it.

I found a way around this by using a div element for the body's content and adjusting the margins for the div. But I'm picky and don't like doing this. I would rather manipulate the body directly. How do I do that?

This is the style sheet code. Pretty self explanatory...

```
body {
   margin-left: 100px;
   margin-right: 100px;
}
```

Comment: So what's the deal with this being downvoted? I don't want to repeat the same mistake.

Comment: Why do you "not like doing this"? I would say doing it on a div is the correct way to do it.

Comment: centring the body, really? why that? and you should show us the *nothing happens*

Comment: It's personal preference. Like how I like using external css instead of internal. I guess I'll leave it at that.

Comment: You're receiving down votes for the very reason the down vote exits (hover your mouse over the down arrow). You need to show what code you've tried.

Comment: @TemaniAfif In bootstrap using container centers the page but when you resize the window smaller, the page re-centers itself funny. I've seen other pages that are alot smoother.

Comment: well, it strange to me, but your are free ... anyway, you need to show us what is not working so we can help, your are not getting downvotes because we don't like the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following solution:

```
body {
    margin:auto;
    width:500px;/*you can set any value*/
}
```